# Where did Heinlein get the name Podkayne?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, podkayne-of-mars

Does the name have an origin prior to *Podkayne of Mars*? A meaning?

Comment: Isn't Podkayne said to be named after a legendary native Martian?  If she is named after a non human person it is quite likely Heinlein simply made up the name instead of using a human name he remembered from somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podkayne at Google ngrams, 1650-1965: [image: The first 2 Google ngram blips for Podkayne are Heinlein's]

The peak at 1957 looks to be a glitch based on a publisher rejiggering one of the Heinlein anthologies. 1963/64 is the original serialization and publication of the story.
The absence of any other literary ref in the previous 300 years makes it look pretty likely that Heinlein came up with the name himself.

Comment: Google nGram data prior to 1800 is, um, to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Wow didn't know about ngram. Useful, as we're considering podkayne as a future baby name.

Answer (score 5):

There's an earlier version of [Poddy in Heinlein's "Puddin'" stories.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinlein_juveniles#Puddin.27_stories_for_girls)  The only one I've read is "Cliff and the Calories" which is good, but not sci-fi.

Comment: It's the same character, but Heinlein "changed her name to 'Podkayne'" when he "moved her to Mars."

Comment: /makes note to get copy of Puddin stories.

Comment: RAH talked about this at some length in Expanded Universe, in the foreword or afterword to "Cliff and the Calories".